# nginx seems to be redirecting http to https without being asked to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, nginx, https

I have two rails sites deployed and running (Can see them in htop) and the site configs are correctly pointing to the unix socket files.

I've also modified my hosts file to point the domain urls to the correct IP address but when I type the URLs in I just get a 'can't connect' error and both chrome and safari seem to be going to a HTTPS site even when you type the full url with HTTP.

This is deployed to AWS EC2.

I've checked all nginx configs and none of them contain a redirection directive, the closest to https is (which I got by running `sudo grep -rnw '/etc/nginx/' -e '443'`):

```
#    listen       443 ssl;
```

which as you can see is commented out, there is nothing telling nginx to redirect yet it is doing so any way.

When I do `curl -i http://websitedomain.com` I get the following headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.12.1
Date: Wed, 20 Sep 2017 09:56:02 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://websitedomain.com/
```

Which suggests it's nginx doing it but as I said there are no redirection directives, I know this because running `sudo grep -rnw '/etc/nginx/' -e 'rewrite'`  returns nothing.

I'm not sure where to look next.

It even redirects `localhost` & `127.0.0.1` to `https://localhost/` & `https://127.0.0.1` respectively when using curl on the server itself.

Here's one of the site config files (with some details altered):

```
upstream app_production {
    server unix:/home/app_user/app_site/production/shared/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}



server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.websitedomain.com;


    root /home/app_user/app_site/production/current/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app_production;
    location @app_production {
    proxy_pass http://app_production;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

I'm not sure where to look next.

output of `nginx -T` (again with some details altered):

```
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
user www-data;
wHorker_processes 1;
daemon off;

er[MaH]ror_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
  work[MaH]er_connections  1024;
}

http {[MaH]

  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_[MaH]type  application/octet-stream;
  charset_types text/css text/plain text/vnd.wap.wml application/javascript application/json application/rss+xml application/xml;

[MaH]
  access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log;

  se[MaH]ndfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
[MaH]
  keepalive_requests 100;
  keepalive_timeout  65;
[MaH]

  gzip  on;
  gz[MaH]ip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_comp_level 2;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_v[MaH]ary off;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml image/svg+xml text/javascript application/javascript application/json text/mathml;
  gzip_min_length  1000;
  gzip_disab[MaH]le     "MSIE [1-6]\.";


        variables_hash[MaH]_max_size 1024;
  variables_hash_bucket_size 64;
  server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  types_hash_bucket_size 64;
  client_max_body_size 50m;



  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:
types {

    # Data interchange

    application/atom+xml                  atom;
    application/json                      json map topojson;
    application/ld+json                   jsonld;
    application/rss+xml                   rss;
    application/vnd.geo+json              geojson;
    application/xml                       rdf xml;


    # JavaScript

    # Normalize to standard type.
    # https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4329#section-7.2
    application/javascript                js;


    # Manifest files

    application/manifest+json             webmanifest;
    application/x-web-app-manifest+json   webapp;
    text/cache-manifest                   appcache;
    text/cache.manifest                   manifest;


    # Media files

    audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
    audio/mp4                             aac f4a f4b m4a;
    audio/mpeg                            mp3;
    audio/ogg                             oga ogg opus;
    audio/x-realaudio                     ra;
    audio/x-wav                           wav;
    image/bmp                             bmp;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    image/png                             png;
    image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
    image/tiff                            tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
    image/webp                            webp;
    image/x-jng                           jng;
    video/3gpp                            3gp 3gpp;
    video/mp4                             f4p f4v m4v mp4;
    video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
    video/ogg                             ogv;
    video/quicktime                       mov;
    video/webm                            webm;
    video/x-flv                           flv;
    video/x-mng                           mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                        asf asx;
    video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                       avi;

    # Serving `.ico` image files with a different media type
    # prevents Internet Explorer from displaying then as images:
    # https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/commit/37b5fec090d00f38de64b591bcddcb205aadf8ee

    image/x-icon                          cur ico;


    # Microsoft Office

    application/msword                                                         doc;
    application/vnd.ms-excel                                                   xls;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint                                              ppt;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    docx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet          xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  pptx;


    # Web fonts

    application/font-woff                 woff;
    application/font-woff2                woff2;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;

    # Browsers usually ignore the font media types and simply sniff
    # the bytes to figure out the font type.
    # https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/#matching-a-font-type-pattern
    #
    # However, Blink and WebKit based browsers will show a warning
    # in the console if the following font types are served with any
    # other media types.

    application/x-font-ttf                ttc ttf;
    font/opentype                         otf;

    # Other

    application/java-archive              ear jar war;
    application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
    application/octet-stream              bin deb dll dmg exe img iso msi msm msp safariextz;
    application/pdf                       pdf;
    application/postscript                ai eps ps;
    application/rtf                       rtf;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
    application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
    application/x-bb-appworld             bbaw;
    application/x-bittorrent              torrent;
    application/x-chrome-extension        crx;
    application/x-cocoa                   cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                run;
    application/x-opera-extension         oex;
    application/x-perl                    pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                   pdb prc;
    application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
    application/x-sea                     sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
    application/x-stuffit                 sit;
    application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert            crt der pem;
    application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
    application/xslt+xml                  xsl;
    application/zip                       zip;
    text/css                              css;
    text/html                             htm html shtml;
    text/mathml                           mml;
    text/plain                            txt;
    text/vcard                            vcard vcf;
    text/vnd.rim.location.xloc            xloc;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
    text/vtt                              vtt;
    text/x-component                      htc;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/http_gzip_static.conf:
gzip_static off;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/http_realip.conf:
set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
real_ip_recursive off;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/app_production:
upstream app_production {
    server unix:/home/app_user/app_site/production/shared/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}



server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.websitedomain.com;


    root /home/app_user/app_site/production/current/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app_production;
    location @app_production {
    proxy_pass http://app_production;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}


# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/app_staging:
upstream app_staging {
    server unix:/home/app_user/app_site/staging/shared/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}



server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.internaldomain.com;


    root /home/app_user/app_site/staging/current/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app_staging;
    location @app_staging {
    proxy_pass http://app_staging;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}


# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/app2_production:
upstream app2_production {
    server unix:/home/app_user/app_site2/production/shared/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}



server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.websitedomain2.com;


    root /home/app_user/app_site2/production/current/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app2_production;
    location @app2_production {
    proxy_pass http://app2_production;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}


# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/app2_staging:
upstream app2_staging {
    server unix:/home/app_user/app_site2/staging/shared/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}



server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.internaldomain2.com;


    root /home/app_user/app_site2/staging/current/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app2_staging;
    location @app2_staging {
    proxy_pass http://app2_staging;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

output of `curl www.websitedomain.com`:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.12.1
Date: Wed, 20 Sep 2017 11:28:41 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-UA-Compatible: chrome=1
Location: http://www.websitedomain.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Request-Id: b031f541-6634-4bdf-8b36-64ee3be2a562
X-Runtime: 0.005923
X-Protected-By: Sqreen

<html><body>You are being <a href="http://www.websitedomain.com">redirected</a>.</body></html>%
```

Comment: Please add output of `nginx -T` to your question

Comment: Added to the OP.

Comment: Looking at the config, I am sure that the redirect is being sent by rails application itself and not nginx

Comment: You were partially correct, I changed the `config.force_ssl` to `true` and it's now curl is now returning something slightly different, see OP.

Comment: Can you remove nginx and then try your app by making a host entry for the host name?